# Merging Two Hashses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, hash

I am using the Google Civic Information API. It is giving me two arrays of hashes. I want to print information from both on the screen. Hash 1 has some integers as a k-v pair (officialIndices). These represent the index number for the corresponding object in the second hash. How can merge these two? I want to display the information from both hashes together.  Maybe it would be better to replace the values of officialIndices with the indexed hash in the second array. Thanks for any advice!

**Hash 1:**

```
{
  "name"       => "President of the United States",
  "divisionId" => "ocd-division/country:us",
  "levels" => ["country"],
  "roles" => ["headOfState", "headOfGovernment"],
  "officialIndices" => [0]
}
```

**Hash 2:**

```
{
  "name" => "Barack Obama",
  "address" => [{
    "line1" => "The White House",
    "line2" => "1600 pennsylvania avenue nw",
    "city" => "washington",
    "state" => "DC",
    "zip" => "20500"
  }],
  "party" => "Democratic",
  "phones" => ["(202) 456-1111"],
  "urls" => ["http://www.whitehouse.gov/"],
  "photoUrl" => "http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/imagecache/admin_official_lowres/administration-official/ao_image/president_official_portrait_hires.jpg",
  "channels" => [
    { "type" => "GooglePlus", "id" => "+whitehouse" },
    { "type" => "Facebook", "id" => "whitehouse" },
    { "type" => "Twitter", "id" => "whitehouse" },
    { "type" => "YouTube", "id" => "barackobama" }
  ]
}
```

EDIT** To clarify, Hash 1 is the first hash in an array of hashes. Hash 2 is the first hash in an array of hashes. I would like to replace the number in officialIndice in Hash 1 with Hash 2. It's confusing me because some officialIndices have more than one number. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You said, "These represent the index number for the corresponding object in the second hash." What is the "corresponding object"? How is that index used in the construction of the merged Hash? Please edit to clarify and show the desired merged Hash for your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge won't work; what will you do if `officialIndices` has multiple elements?

```
array1.each do |el1|
  el1["officials"] = el1["officialIndices"].map { |idx|
    array2[idx]
  }
  el1.delete("officialIndices")
end
```

(Note: this is destructive, i.e. it will change `array1`. If you want `array1` unchanged, I'll rewrite.)

Comment: I would suggest `el1["officials"] = array2.values_at(*el1["officialIndices"])`. You've been AWOL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) with a block:

```
foo = { "name" => "President of the United States" }
bar = { "name" => "Barack Obama" }

foo.merge(bar) { |key, old_val, new_val| {description: old_val, value: new_val} }
=> {"name"=>{:description=>"President of the United States", 
             :value=>"Barack Obama"}}
```

So, you can specify your `merge` logic by this way. This solution effective if you have more than 1 overlapping key with similar logic.

Comment: Thank you. That would be true, but I wasn't fully clear. Hash 1 is the first hash in an array of hashes. Hash 2 is the first hash in an array of hashes. I want to just combine the information from these two hashes. I can do that by taking the officialIndice, and plugging that into the second array. The officialIndice represents the index number of the second hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Hash#merge` to merge information from two hashes. However, you have an overlapping key (`name`) in both, so you'll want to rename it either hash before merging:

```
# Rename "name" to "position_name" before merging to prevent collision
hash1["position_name"] = hash1.delete("name")

merged_hash = hash1.merge(hash2)
```